# Query works with hardcode, variables don't return correct response/general efficiency in statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

first questions on SO.

I'm getting back into SQL and having some issues with this current task. I have a large structured DB that uses a singular id with multiple lookup tables, so coreid = nameid = transactid, etc, etc, etc.

What I'm trying to do is create a view, where when passed the coreid, will pull that persons' data, while also searching the 'relation' table for his spouse, and bringing up their record in core as well.

If I hardcode the following:

```
select *
from core 
where coreid in (select relid from relations where relisa ='sp' and relid ='913')
or coreid in (select relrelatid from relations where relisa ='sp' and relid = '913')

select *
from corebio 
where coreid in ('913', (select relrelatid from relations where relisa ='sp' and     relid = '913'))

select *
from corebio 
where coreid in (select relid from relations where relisa ='sp' and relid = '913'
             union
             select relrelatid from relations where relisa ='sp' and relid = '913')
```

They all work as expected. I get two rows from core, one from the 'relid' which is the same as 'coreid', and one from 'relrelatid' which is the same formatted id but links the relationship, in this case a spouse (relisa='sp').

If I pop any of these queries into a view, like so:

```
select *
from core 
where coreid in (select relid from relations where relisa ='sp' and relid = coreid)
or coreid in (select relrelatid from relations where relisa ='sp' and relid = coreid)
```

And call

```
select *
from nameSpouseView
where coreid = '913'
```

I get one row, the row of the id I requested. I'm stumped and I've been looking at this thing for hours. Any thoughts to what I'm sure is a blatantly obvious omission? Also, in regards to the three original queries, which would be considered the most efficient? Is there are more efficient method I should be using?

Thanks for all your help, this site has been a huge learning tool.

Comment: I don't see where you're using any variables

Comment: And what is the SQL you are using to query the view?

Comment: The second bit of code is the view. You can substitute any of the above queries with the '913' value. Variable might be the wrong term, but in the view I've replaced '913' with coreid, which is the value I'm passing when calling the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achive that with a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE core_relations
    @coreid varchar(10), --is this an INT?
    @relisa varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN

select *
from core 
where 
coreid in (@coreid,(select relrelatid from relations where relisa = @relisa and relid = @coreid))

END
```

Example:

```
EXEC core_relations '913','sp'
```